# WFS success with error

Tags: geoserver, wfs, openlayers-2, proxy

I am trying to load a WFS from GeoServer. My GeoServer service is at localhost:8080 and my web server at localhost:80. Since there is the issue of cross domain and firebug is showing:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs. 
Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```

I have created a proxy.cgi following http://www.gistutor.com/geoserver/21-intermediate-geoserver-tutorials/38-configuring-geoserver-proxy-for-public-and-remote-data-access.html. But when I go to http://localhost/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi its giving me the OpenLayers site, and when there is no proxy and just leading to http://localhost/xampp, when there is a proxy (here proxy is my institute proxy to connect to internet)..

My problem is I am able to load the data from GeoServer successfully (as if everything is fine) but firebug is showing:

```
"POST *http://localhost/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fgeoserver%2Fwfs undefined (undefined)".
```

I am including `OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=";` in my JavaScript and also:

```
protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
            version: "1.0.0",
            srsName: "EPSG:4326", // this is the default
            url:  "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs",
            featureType: "states",
            featureNS: "http://www.openplans.org/topp"
        }),
```

I want to know why it's working fine but  still giving me the error, What is the error about and how can I to fix it?

Comment: @user1975 please only link to public urls - hyperlinking localhost is not useful to GISse users here. If you can put the application on a public url (webserver) where it is much easier to debug. (I removed the local hyperlinks...)

Comment: @Mapperz, thanks for informing, will not repeat this

Comment: try using the full IP address of your 'localhost' - also try from another machine (i use remote desktop to do this)